# Reading files using distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-caching

I have a lot of files stored in the distributed cache, each corresponding to a user id. I want to attach a specific file corresponding to a particular user id(which will be the key of the reducer), to a particular reduce task. But I am not able to do so, because, I read the files from distributed cache using the configure method, which comes before the reduce method in the reduce class. So I cannot access the keys of the reduce method in the configure method of the reduce class, and hence can't read only the file that I want to. Pls help me.

```
class reduce{

void configure(args)
{

/*I can a particular file from the Path[] here.
I want to select the  file corresponding to the key of the reduce method and pass its
contents to the reduce method. I am not able to do this as I can't access the key of 
the reduce method.*/

}

void reduce(args)
{
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to assign the `Path` arrays from the DistributedCache to class variables during the configure step as described in the DistributedCache [javadocs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html).  Of course, replace the map code with your reduce code.

This is using the old API, which it looked like your code was using.

```
 public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase  
 implements Mapper<K, V, K, V> {

   private Path[] localArchives;
   private Path[] localFiles;

   public void configure(JobConf job) {
     // Get the cached archives/files
     localArchives = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheArchives(job);
     localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
   }

   public void map(K key, V value, 
                   OutputCollector<K, V> output, Reporter reporter) 
   throws IOException {
     // Use data from the cached archives/files here
     // ...
     // ...
     output.collect(k, v);
   }
 }
```